# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'reactAlertEvents' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I am getting below error while upgrading to webpack 4 in React App. I tried to find the solution in internet but this issue doesn't exist.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'reactAlertEvents' of undefined
at new AlertContainer (alert.js?5001:528)
at eval (ReactCompositeComponent.js?888e:294)
at measureLifeCyclePerf (ReactCompositeComponent.js?888e:75)
at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper._constructComponentWithoutOwner (ReactCompositeComponent.js?888e:293)
at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper._constructComponent (ReactCompositeComponent.js?888e:284)
at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.mountComponent (ReactCompositeComponent.js?888e:187)
at Object.mountComponent (ReactReconciler.js?37a8:43)
at ReactDOMComponent.mountChildren (ReactMultiChild.js?0cbd:234)
at ReactDOMComponent._createInitialChildren (ReactDOMComponent.js?17ad:703)
at ReactDOMComponent.mountComponent (ReactDOMComponent.js?17ad:522)
```

Comment: Is `AlertContainer` your own component? Could you include that in your question?

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: Nope I don't have such component in my app.Looks like its an error from react.

Comment: @Colin are you asking for webpack code?

Comment: No.. your application code.

Comment: There are many components. Not sure in which component causing this issue

Comment: Voting to close under the official close reason: _Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers._